# C# Use async/await on UdpClient Receive

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, udpclient

The following code uses Task to receive asyncronously and shows the received result in the console:

```
private void ReceiveMessage()
{
    Task.Run(async() => 
    {
         using(var udpClient = new UdpClient(15000))
         {
             while(true)
             {
                 var receivedResult = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
                 Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedResult.Buffer));
             }
         }
    });
}
```

I want to learn how to use async/await functions so I would like to know **how to make the function ReceiveMessage() asynchronously by using async/await?**

Comment: Which "following function"?

Comment: I see only one function in question... @RenéVogt

Comment: I think you might to want to give [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) a read..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the whole method to be awaitable, simply change it to that:

```
private async Task ReceiveMessage()
{
     using(var udpClient = new UdpClient(15000))
     {
         while(true)
         {
             var receivedResult = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
             Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedResult.Buffer));
         }
     }
}
```

You don't need `Task.Run()` anymore, which would use a thread. That thread is not needed. The method now returns to the caller while `await`ing `ReceiveAsync()`.
When `ReceiveAsync()` finishes, the method is (eventually) resumed at `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: Actually this code is correct, but it does not make the method awaitable as you mention. You can't await void, you await Tasks.

Comment: @Trickzter fair enough, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another async/await to your function:

```
private async void receiveMessage()
{
    await Task.Run(async() => 
    {
         using(var udpClient = new UdpClient(15000))
         {
             while(true)
             {
                 var receivedResult = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
                 Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedResult.Buffer));
             }
         }
    });
}
```

If you want to write a method being awaitable, return a task:

```
private Task foo(){
    Task doStuff = new Task(() => {});
    doStuff.Start();
    return doStuff;
};

//Another method
private async void bar()
{
    await foo();
}
```

**Update:**
As mentioned below, you do really not need the execution of that task on a thread inside the thread pool. It's not wrong, but useless. For better usage, you can use:

```
private async void receiveMessage()
{
     using(var udpClient = new UdpClient(15000))
     {
         while(true)
         {
             var receivedResult = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
             Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedResult.Buffer));
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: The `Task.Run()` is unnecessarily using a thread from the thread pool. Since `ReceiveAsync()` is already `await`ed, this is a waste of resources.

Comment: That's totally correct, but not point of discussion here. He was only asking for a way to make it working asynchronously and I just completed the code. But you are right sir.

Comment: The purpose of SO is to give helpful answers that can help future readers, too. Of course you answered OP's immediate question, but even he states that he _wants to learn_. Showing bad code as a good example has a little smell.

Comment: @RenéVogt agreed.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is valid if you want it to be fire and forget, listening on a separate thread. If you not want this, I would remove the `Task.Run` and be sure to return a `Task` in your method, like this:

```
private async Task ReceiveMessage()
{
    using (var udpClient = new UdpClient(15000))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var receivedResult = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
            Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedResult.Buffer));
        }
    }
}
```