# C# UdpClient Receive works, ReceiveAsync hangs

Tags: c#, udpclient

I'm currently trying to refactor some old code and reached a point where I'm trying to get UDP communication asynchronous. My old code receives packets:

```
ClientListener = new UdpClient(ClientListenPort);
ServerEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, ClientListenPort);
try
{
    while (!stop)
    {
         byte[] ReceivedData = ClientListener.Receive(ref ServerEp);
         LastReceivedTimeMS = Environment.TickCount;
         if (!FoundServer)
         {
             ServerIP = ServerEp.Address.ToString();
             FoundServer = true;
         }
         HandleReceiveData(ReceivedData);
     }
}
 catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log("Error: " + e);
}
```

whereas the asynchronous way does not receive anything (hangs). Does someone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
ClientListener = new UdpClient(ClientListenPort);
ServerEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, ClientListenPort);
try
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            UdpReceiveResult receivedResults = await ClientListener.ReceiveAsync();
            if (!FoundServer)
            {
                ServerIP = receivedResults.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString();
                ServerEp = receivedResults.RemoteEndPoint;
                FoundServer = true;
            }
            HandleReceiveData(receivedResults.Buffer);
        }
    });
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log("Error: " + e);
}
```

Comment: When you say 'does not receive anything' do you mean that the program quits right away?

Comment: At UdpReceiveResult receivedResults = await ClientListener.ReceiveAsync(); it awaits endless, so there is no error and it doesnt quit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Use async/await on UdpClient Receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428589/c-sharp-use-async-await-on-udpclient-receive)

Comment: The try/catch is not doing anything since it only checks if Task.Run throws, you should put the try/catch inside the delegate.

Comment: @JonasH that's answer, there was an error in HandleRecieveData... Thanks